# Do we have for all $M \in SL_n(\Bbb K)$, $\lVert M \rVert \geq 1$ when $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ is a matrix norm?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant, normed-spaces, matrix-norms

Let be $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ a matrix norm (submultiplicative).

Do we have for all matrices of determinant 1, the following lower bound:

$$\lVert M \rVert \geq 1$$

I'm very confused and could not find any counterexample and I find this statement very fishy, I tried to experiment with:

\begin{bmatrix}
1&  x \\
0&  1
\end{bmatrix}

But, its Frobenius norm cannot be small enough.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[The norm of a matrix is larger than its eigenvalues](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855044/why-is-the-norm-of-a-matrix-larger-than-its-eigenvalue/). The determinant is the product of its eigenvalues. So, if the determinant of $M$ is $1$, there must be at least one eigenvalue $\lambda$ such that $|\lambda| \ge 1$, which implies
$$\|M\| \ge |\lambda| \ge 1,$$
regardless of the matrix norm used.

Answer (score 3):

If $\| \cdot \|$ is a matrix norm then $\rho(A) \leq \| A\|$ and $\rho(A) = 1$

Answer (score 2):

If $\lVert M\rVert<1$, then, if $B$ is the closed unit ball, the volume of $M(B)$ will be smaller than the valume of $B$. But that cannot happen because, sense, $\det M=1$, the map $v\mapsto M.v$ must preserve volumes.

Comment: I understand better, I don't have a good definition of volume, is there a way to get this result without using volumes?

Comment: I expect so, but I was unable to find another proof.

Answer (score 1):

Well, in fact, I just got it.

$SL_n(\Bbb K)$ is closed.

If I suppose that $\lVert M \rVert < 1$, then: $M^n \in SL_n(\Bbb K)$ for all $n$, and then: $M^n \to 0$ for $\lVert \cdot \rVert$, thus: we derive a contradiction.

Which yields the result.

Comment: Wouldn't $\|M\| < 1$ mean $\|M^n\| \le \|M\|^n < 1$, and hence $M^n \notin SL_n(\Bbb{K})$?

Comment: Why $M^n \not \in SL_n(\Bbb K)$ ? It's not a *then* logical, but rather, by product, you must say in the subgroup, and at the same time, your norm converges to 0, so you must be the null matrix, but the null matrix is not in the set, and the set is closed, so…

Comment: @TheoBendit I think we're saying the same thing maybe