# Find $\sup\limits_{A \in C}|\lambda(A)|$ and $\inf\limits_{A \in C}|\lambda(A)|$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm stuck in solving this problem and would be glad for some hints on the solution.

On a linear space of dimension $4$ over the field $\mathbb{R}$, a class of linear operators $C$ is given.
For any operator $A$ from class $C$ the following holds:
For any operator $A$ from class $C$ the following holds:

- All eigenvalues ​​of $A$ are real.
- In one of the bases of the original space $\phi$ : $rank(A_{\phi})=2$ and $tr(A_{\phi}A_{\phi}^T)=5$, where $A_{\phi}$ is the matrix $A$ in the basis $\varphi$.

Find $\sup\limits_{A \in C}|\lambda(A)|$ and $\inf\limits_{A \in C}|\lambda(A)|$, where $\lambda(A)$ - the maximum modulo eigenvalue of the operator $A$.

Attempts to solve this problem gave me the following properties of these operators.

1.$\lambda_1,\lambda_2=0$( where $\lambda$ i is the ith eigenvalue)

2.$\sum_{i,j}a^2_{i,j}=5$  where $a_{i,j}$ is the elements of  matrix $A_{\phi}$

It seems to me that I need to somehow express the tr(A) in terms of tr($AA^T$), but how

Comment: Hint: $\sqrt{\operatorname{tr}(AA^\top)}$ is also known as the [Frobenius Norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm#Frobenius_norm) of $A$, which is a type of matrix norm. Like all matrix norms, it satisfies [$\|A\|_F \ge |\lambda(A)|$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2855044/why-is-the-norm-of-a-matrix-larger-than-its-eigenvalue/).